# Laravel 5.2: Homestead provisioning returns database already exists error after reinstall

Tags: php, virtualbox, laravel-5, homestead, vagrant-provision

I think I'm misunderstanding the way Homestead works. I want a [per project installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#per-project-installation), but something weird happened. My steps are:

1. Run vagrantbox (vagrant up). Database homestead is created. Up & running.
2. Halt the vagrantbox (vagrant halt)
3. **Delete** the box from VirtualBox client.
4. Run vagrant up again. Of course, box need to be downloaded.
5. During the "up" process, I get the error:

   createdb: database creation failed: ERROR: database "homestead" already exists

**How is it possible? Does vagrant create the database somewhere in my host machine and reuse it for different installations?**

My host is a Mac OS X machine (El Capitan). I generated the Vagrantfile with

```
php vendor/bin/homestead make
```

My Vagrantfile is:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("vendor/laravel/homestead", File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = "Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = "Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = "after.sh"
aliasesPath = "aliases"

require File.expand_path(confDir + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

And my Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: laraveltest
name: laraveltest
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Users/jorge/Dev/laraveltest"
      to: "/home/vagrant/laraveltest"

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/laraveltest/public"

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: looking forward to an answer, as I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I ssh'd into the machine, I had to manually run the following script to run the migration scripts.

php artisan migrate

Not sure why the homestead installation scripts are not picking up this migration script.